# Unexpected tASSOC, in a chef recipe. What's wrong?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

I keep getting the an error when I try to use the `environment` attribute in a chef recipe:

```
git name do
        repository repo_url 
        revision "master"
        environment  { 'VAR' => 'whatever' }
        action :sync
      end
```

The error is :

```
ERROR: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-3/cookbooks/JandJ/recipes/git_repo.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'
==> default:            environment  { 'VAR' => 'whatever' }
```

I copied the example from the chef docs [here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html)

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be either

```
environment({ 'VAR' => 'whatever' })
```

or

```
environment 'VAR' => 'whatever'
```

Comment: Strange I copied it from the chef documentation `environment  { 'VAR' => 'whatever' }`...Anyway it is not giving me a no method found error. `: undefined method `environment' for Chef::Resource::Git`